# Setup OpenCV 2.3 w/ python bindings in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, opencv

How to install OpenCV (exactly 2.3.*, not 2.1.*) with python bindings in Ubuntu (or generally, in Linux)? I've seen few manuals on Windows installations, but none for Linux.
I've read and used [instructions from willow garage site](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide):

```
wget downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2
tar -xvf OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2
cd OpenCV-2.3.1/
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=OFF -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
make
sudo make install
```

All seems to be ok, except that `make install` output does not mention python.
After that I'm trying to import opencv module in python REPL:

```
~$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy # so numpy is installed
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In case people stumble over this, in Ubuntu just install the `python-opencv` package if you don't need to use the newest versions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you installed the Python development headers?

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Recompile it with those installed.

Comment: Yep, I've missed that step. Now, I've installed headers, restarted `make`s and all goes fine.

Comment: Did it install the Python modules too?